# Optional Where clause that won't affect performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to know if there is a way to do this kind of query (optional where clause) without putting such a load on sql.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TABLE 
 WHERE 
  Name = IsNull(@Name,Name) 
  AND (
       (@MinAge IS NULL AND @MaxAge IS NULL)
       OR
       (@MinAge IS NOT NULL AND @MaxAge IS NOT NULL AND Age BETWEEN @MinAge AND @MaxAge) 
      )
```

I know I could execute it as a variable using `EXEC` and include the query where needed, like this:

```
   SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE'
   IF(@Name IS NOT NULL) SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE Name = ''+@Name+'''
   EXEC(@sql)
```

But I want to avoid this option ^^^

Any other options in the SQL world that I'm unaware of?

The first query puts a heavier load cost on SQL than needed.

Comment: This article by Erland Sommarskog is the most extensive resource on the matter that I know of. [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three possible options:

**OPTION RECOMPILE**

Advise the server to recompile the query during every execution. It should be able to detect the NULL-values and optimize accordingly then.
The disadvantage is obviously the recompilation during every execution.

**OPTIMIZE FOR**

Tell the server to optimize the query for the parameters set. There you do have only one execution-plan, but you do not risk that it changes due to an unfortunate first query.

**Write it twice**

Put in an IF-Statement and have the query twice.
This does not scale very well of course if you have many parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for **NOT NULL** when you're doing **BETWEEN**, it'll fail the condition if either @MinAge or @MaxAge are null. In other words, you can rewrite your WHERE clause as follows...

```
WHERE Name = IsNull(@Name,Name) 
  AND (
        (@MinAge IS NULL AND @MaxAge IS NULL)
        OR
        (Age BETWEEN @MinAge AND @MaxAge) 
      )
```

One other option that I generally try to avoid is to check for the statuses of your variables with if-else then branch into two separate select statements depending on the outcome. In other words...

```
IF @MinAge IS NULL AND @MaxAge IS NULL 
    SELECT <columnlist>
    FROM TABLE 

ELSE
    SELECT <columnlist>
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Age BETWEEN @MinAge AND @MaxAge
```